# How to migrate a Carrierwave file to a column in another model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, data-migration

I have an existing model that stores a file using Carrierwave. I would like to move that file to a new model, but I can't seem to read the file properly

Here is my existing model:

```
class ShipmentNote < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shipment_note_files # this is actually the new model I want to move the files to
  mount_uploader :file, DocumentUploader
  ....
end
```

And my new model:

```
class ShipmentNoteFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shipment_note
  mount_uploader :file, DocumentUploader
end
```

This is what I thought would work:

```
ShipmentNote.where.not(file: nil).each do |shipment_note|
  # create a new file in the shipment_note_files
  shipment_note.shipment_note_files.create(file: shipment_note.file)
  # remove from shipment_note
  shipment_note.remove_file!
  shipment_note.save
end
```

But it is throwing the following error, implying that the file field is empty:

```
PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "file" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (15, null, 46689, 2019-02-07 20:56:54.503714, 2019-02-07 20:56:54.503714, null).
: INSERT INTO "shipment_note_files" ("file", "shipment_note_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the file really didn't exist on S3. I had to rescue the error and all worked well:

```
ShipmentNote.where.not(file: nil).each do |shipment_note|
  begin
    # create a new file in the shipment_note_files
    shipment_note.shipment_note_files.create(file: shipment_note.file)
    # remove from shipment_note
    shipment_note.remove_file!
    shipment_note.save
  rescue => exception
    p "file not exist: #{shipment_note.id}"
  end
end
```